# Modulo in C,wrong output

Tags: c

I have an really annoying problem in my simple C program and I can't see why isn't this code working.

This is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

   int main()
{

    unsigned long long podstawa,wykladnik;
    unsigned int d;


    scanf("%d",&d);
    while(d>0)
    {
        d--;
        scanf("%d %d",&podstawa,&wykladnik);

        printf("%d %d",(podstawa%10),(wykladnik%10) );

    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you compile this program you will be able to see that even though inputting the data is correct.

`Wykladnik%10` gives wrong number.

For example the value of `podstawa` and `wykladnik` is 3 and while `podstawa%10` prints out 3 `wykladnik%10` prints out 5.

This error is interesting because value of `wykladnik%10` is always bigger than it should be by 2 and I have no idea why.

I hope I provided enough information and somebody is able to help me. I've been trying to find this error for 10 minutes and I still can't see it.

Comment: print out podstawa and wykladnik right after the scanf

Comment: Try using `%llu` instead of `%d`

Answer (score 5):

You are getting the wrong output because of the wrong specifier used for your data types. It will invoke *undefined behavior*.  Change your format specifier from `%d` to `%llu` for `unsigned long long` and `%u` for `unsigned int`

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong format specifier try `"%llu"`.